# Make CouchDB vhosts rule via PUT request

Tags: curl, couchdb

I wish make working with public CouchDB database only via **_rewrite**
I add string to *local.ini* to *vhosts*:

```
*/mydb = /mydb/_design/doc/_rewrite
```

It's working good, all requests to *http://localhost:5984/mydb* redirect to *_rewrite*

But I can't make this vhosts rule via futon, or via curl. Futon return me error in jquery.couch.js.

I dont know how make this curl valid:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
        -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/_config/vhosts/*/mydb \
        -d '{"/mydb/_design/doc/_rewrite"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it's possible to change the configuration of couchDB via the http-interface, if that is what you want to do.

Comment: Petter, it's possible. futon make PUT requests to various parts of _config. For example: post to http://127.0.0.1:5984/_config/vhosts add virtual host.